# iphone development: how to set a property of an another viewController then reach it

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Lets say I have two viewcontrollers `ViewControllerA` and `ViewControllerB` when I press a button from `viewcontrollerA` it is pushing to `viewControllerB`. However before pushing I want to set a property of `viewControllerB` from `viewControllerA`. But all I get is `nil` value when I check the variable from `viewControllerB`. What I do is;

In `ViewControllerA`:

```
VCB = [[ViewControllerB alloc]init];
[VCB setPropertyOfViewControllerB:someString];
NSLog(@"value: %@", VCB.PropertyOfViewControllerB); // Here I observe the correct value so I set successfully
```

but the thing is I also want to reach it from `viewControllerB` but I get `nil` for the variable.

In `ViewControllerB`:

```
//I already defined in h file as property
NSString *PropertyOfViewControllerB;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *PropertyOfViewControllerB;
```

But when I try to check the value in viewDidLoad method of ViewControllerB

```
NSLog(@"value: %@", PropertyOfViewControllerB);//here I get null not the value I set at viewControllerA
```

Probably I miss a small point I could not figure out. Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

---

Edit: I am using storyboards. I push with the following code:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
    lvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainManu"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:lvc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Did you use a Storyboard? Please also show the code, how you push your ViewController.

Comment: @xapslock yes I use storyboard. I edited the answer to show how I push

Comment: maybe this is useful: Passing Data between View Controllers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: @brianLikeApple still getting null

Comment: @TomCobo thanks I looked at it before. it is really useful but i want to figure out why my approach does not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `VCB = [[ViewControllerB alloc]init];` but push via Storyboard, then VCB is not the same ViewController used in Storyboard.
Try this:

```
 - (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"yourSegueName"]) {
         ViewControllerB *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
         [vc setPropertyOfViewControllerB:@"foo"];
     }  
}
```

Comment: yes I see your point but the thing is I dont want to use that delegate method because in my application when a button pressed first I want make some assignments (data coming from a webservice) so I have to be sure that all the data is collected and assigned to the properties then i want to push. but in your answer it pushes immediately.

Comment: No, prepareForSegue: will automatically called before every VC will be pushed. You can do your stuff, webservice, etc. and then call     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueName" sender:self];

Comment: I think I solved the problem with your approach I just added [vc setPropertyOfViewControllerB:@"foo"]; in my version of pushing and it worked...thanks